# Using App.config for path to folder

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I have the following code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "build.bat";
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Build";
proc.Start();
```

and I wanted to move the `WorkingDirectory` to `app.config`

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="buildPath" value="C:\\Build" ></add>
</appSettings>
```

with the new code:

```
string buildPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["buildPath"];
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "build.bat";
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = buildPath;
proc.Start();
```

But it seems that the application can't find the path.

> The system cannot find the file specified.

What is configuration doing behind the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copied the value from C# to your app.config you left the escape sequence from C# (\). You should use just one \

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="buildPath" value="C:\Build" ></add>
</appSettings>
```

That is probably tripping up your code.

Comment: yeah, it works, it was the escape sequence, choosing the first answer

Answer (score 1):

XML config is read exactly as-is, so you don't need to escape the backslash.  This should be fine:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="buildPath" value="C:\Build" ></add>
</appSettings>
```